# Mailgun. Why is there not a list displayed, what could be the error?

Tags: mailgun, html-templates

Mailgun HTML template:

[image: HTML Template of email]

Request:

[image]

Result - empty list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```html
"h:X-Mailgun-Variables": JSON.stringify({ links: data.links })
```